# Following web3.js docs raises TypeError: .once is not a function

Tags: web3js

I deployed  a contract which has a function recordData(bizname, id) function.  I have a expressjs api layer. I want to make sure that when the function is called from this api layer using web3 the transaction is completed

```
contract.recordData('abc', 123, {from: '0x123...'})
.once('transactionHash', function(hash){ ... })
.once('receipt', function(receipt){ ... })
.on('confirmation', function(confNumber, receipt){ ... })
.on('error', function(error){ ... })
.then(function(receipt){
    // will be fired once the receipt its mined
});
```

when i run this i get TypeError: .once is not a function.

Comment: Which framework are you using? You are using `once` but it doesn't seem to be a standard function for javascript.

Comment: hello @ismael I am using a library called web3js http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/callbacks-promises-events.html

Comment: It says in the top of the page _This documentation is work in progress and web3.js 1.0 is not yet released! You can find the current documentation for web3 0.x.x at github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API._

Comment: Hi @Ismael - I'd be tempted to add your comment as an answer, just to make it more obvious to anyone who has similar issues, and doesn't bother to read your comments (as well as the wiki page... ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says in the top of the page http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/callbacks-promises-events.html:

> This documentation is work in progress and web3.js 1.0 is not yet
>   released! You can find the current documentation for web3 0.x.x at
>   github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API.

It is unfortunate but the only documentation available in readthedocs is for the unreleased 1.0 version, hopefully it will released soon. But until then the documentation for 0.xx is at https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using web3 non-1.0, you can add a `waitForReceipt()` function to check the receipt every 1 second, which is also taught in [here](https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2017/12/13/building-decentralized-apps-with-ethereum-and-javascript/):

```
contract.myFunction(arg1, arg2, { from: ... })
.then((txhash) => {
  waitForReceipt(txhash.tx, () => {
    .. to something ..
  })
})
function waitForReceipt(txhash, callback) {
  console.log(txhash)
  this.state.web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(txhash, (error, receipt) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
    if (receipt !== null) {
      if (callback)
        callback(receipt)
    } else {
      // Try again in 1 second
      window.setTimeout(function () {
        waitForReceipt(txhash, callback)
      }, 1000)
    }
  })
}
```